# How to add popup in native camera view?

Tags: react-native, popup

I have a native camera view built with native Android and IOS, I used NativeModules to manage the communication between the react-native and Android camera activity.

Also, when the user finishes video recording, a prompt popup should be presented to ask the user for the video name. This popup has to be displayed over the Android/IOS camera activity. This popup is built with JSX in React Native.

Is there any way to display this JSX code (popup) inside native view?

```
<Modal>
... 
</Modal>
```

Is it possible to do that with react-native?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: thanks for the editing.

Comment: I am not sure this question will get a good reception, unfortunately - I think it should have been put on hold before putting a bounty on it was possible. It's rather broad, and there doesn't seem to be any prior research shown - can you outline for your readers what you have tried?

Comment: Im totally new in mobile area in general and react-native in particular, so im not sure what to do in these situations, already searched in this problem for the past two days, but nothing comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera)? You can use it to embed both the camera view and any needed overlay elements easily. They have a pretty good [example](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md) which you can use as a starting point (show your the overlay at the end of `takePicture` method).

Comment: the requirements needs a native camera view